# Links not working on js-mindmap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just found this js for creating a mindmap, and the only thing that doesn't work are the links. I'm linking to the github as it would be way too much code to place here: https://github.com/kennethkufluk/js-mindmap

I've tried this so far..

```
$('.node.active').mousedown( function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    window.location(url, '_blank');
});
```

Still learning javascript/jquery :)

Thanks for everything!!!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a solution, I made a small workaround for this.

Since my main "bubbles" are just containers, their href value is #, while the last items on each bubble are real links.

So, in script.js on the function that starts with

```
var addLI = function() {
```

change the onlick function to this

```
  onclick:function(node) {
    var thelink = $(this).attr('href');
    if ( thelink != '#' ) {
        window.open(thelink, '_blank');
    }
    else {
        $(node.obj.activeNode.content).each(function() {
          this.hide();
        });
        $(node.content).each(function() {
          this.show();
        });
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: just need to add one more "}" on the end.

Answer (score 0):

For opening a new window every time you need to use [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

```
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Comment: Ok that doesn't do anything still :/ I'm not sure what's stopping the links from just working properly in the code I downloaded

Comment: is the url relative one or a complete url

Comment: the code snippet I posted is on my local copy of the github code: https://github.com/kennethkufluk/js-mindmap Links are complete

Comment: can you tell me the value of `href`

Comment: It's different for each link

Comment: looks like there is only one `.node.active` like and it is working for me

Comment: Whichever .node is clicked gets an added .active, so it changes, though only one at a time. When you say working fine, do you mean it's linking and pulling up the correct pages? Just tried your update and it still doesn't work :/

Comment: which is the jquery version used and why is the href of the active item `\\`

Comment: will you be able to use jquery 1.7 >=

Comment: I just changed mine to 1.9.1 to see if that made a difference, and no good, I don't see any active items with a href of '\'

Comment: the element `Kenneth` has href=/

Comment: Ok, I see that now, I'm not clicking that one though.. I think that changes to / when it's acting as the activeparent so you can go back to the main level, that's how it comes, not sure

Comment: Again there seems to be some problem with the js-mindmap.js file, it is not allowing the click event to propagate and is preventing default action also.

Comment: That's what I figured, I don't know enough javascript/jquery to figure that out at all.. I was just hoping to override that

Answer (score 0):

You may try this,it would open in new window

```
var a=$(this).attr('href').attr('target','_blank');
```